# Range and null space

Tags: matrices

For a given $N \times 1$ vector $x$, $x \neq 0$, consider the matrix $R = xx^H$. Identify the range space and null space of $R$, and thus determine its rank. Here $H$ is a Hermitian operator.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and look good. Also, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: You can determine the rank from the dimension of the null space alone, using the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For every vector $y$, $Ry=(x^Hy)x$ where $x^Hy$ is a scalar.